# Releasing Objects in Functions

Tags: function, object, vb6

I have read countless times that you should always release objects at the end of your projects, such as:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = GetObject(, "xxxxxx.Application")

    ' Code your project...

    Set obj = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, I use a program that calls upon Excel's object. I call Excel's object so often in so many different routines, I decided to make a function to make things simpler:

```
Public Function appXL As Object
   Set appXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
End Function
```

Although that is an extremely simple function, there is no way for me to release the object `appXL` at the end of any subroutine I use, at least as far as I am aware. But a bigger concern that I have is that a subroutine that uses `appXL` 100+ times is actually grabbing the object the same number of times.

I honestly don't see why it would be a big issue since I am using `GetObject` as opposed to `CreateObject`. I am not creating a new instance of Excel everytime the function is called, so is this something that I should be concerned about when coding? Do I just need to completely get rid of the function and declare `appXL` on every routine I use so I am able to release it in the end?

Comment: The premise of your statement is wrong. You have no need to release objects. There are released at every `end sub`/`end function`. If implicitly declared at the end of that line. Also while a bit slower `getobject` doesn't really matter as you suspect. Don't be afraid to use global variables if it makes sense. If you are accessing the same object from other functions make it a global. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing/ (he wrote a lot of VBScript).

Comment: Also see my answer here for other links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215460/declaring-variables-memory-leaks

Comment: This is the COM object that manages running apps and GetObject uses IRunningObjectTable https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695276(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Your big concern should be automating instances of Excel *at all*.  There are so many ways for this to go wrong and hang your program, corrupt data in another open Workbook, leave Excel running after your program ends, etc. It should be a last resort if no other alternative exists.

Comment: Appreciate the knowledge on this. Thanks!

Comment: Just for emphasis, I repeat the link to this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing/